# cakephp3- unable to show count of values

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to show number of users present in a room. But when I try to do that, I get error.

This is the **relationship**.

```
Rooms has many users.
Rooms belong to groups.

public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->table('rooms');
    $this->displayField('name');
    $this->primaryKey('id');

    $this->belongsTo('Groups', [
        'foreignKey' => 'group_id'
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('Users', [
        'foreignKey' => 'room_id'
    ]);
}
```

To achieve this, I wrote a **controller function** which looks like this:

```
public function index()
{
   $this->loadComponent('Prg');
   $this->Prg->commonProcess();
   $params = $this->Prg->parsedParams();
   $this->paginate = [
    'limit'  => 25,
    'order' => ['id' => 'ASC'], 
    'finder' => ['RoomsList' =>['filter'=> $params]],
    'sortWhitelist' => ['Rooms.id','Rooms.name'],
    'extraOptions' =>['params' => $params]
    ];

   $rooms = $this->paginate($this->Rooms);
   $this->set(compact('rooms'));
   $this->set('_serialize', ['rooms']);
}
```

This function paginates the list of rooms available. This is working fine but now when I try to show the count of users in each room, it throws error.

I modified my **model function** like this:

```
public function findRoomsList(Query $query, array $options)
{ 
    $query->select(['id','name','modified','created'])
    ->contain([
                    'Groups'=> function ($query) {
                        return $query->select(['id','name']);
                    },
                    'Users' => function($query){
                        return $query->select(['status','full_name']);
                        //want to fetch total number of users
                    }
            ]);

    echo $query;
    return $query;
}
```

Now I'm getting this error:

```
You are required to select the "Users.room_id" field(s)
```

Can anyone tell me the mistakes I made here? I'm new to CakePHP3.

Comment: Did you try including room_id in the list of fields you're selecting in the Users containment?